# Need to have blacklisting of Endpoints on Prometheus/Alertmanager

Tags: devops, monitoring, prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager

Creating a blacklist configuration in Prometheus/Alertmanger that allow excluding individual hosts and/or host/service combinations from creating alerts, e.g.:

```yaml
blacklist_endpoints:

name: blacklisted_URLs
host: "test_URL"
labels: <label>
```

The above URLs should not create alerts no matter if it present in some other rules, In other words, These should be the priority if matching here.
Any Idea will be useful or any approach which we can take for achieving this.